# Custom pointer types and container/allocator typedefs

Tags: c++, c++11

C++ standard containers and allocators provide typedefs for the pointer type used by the container, i.e.:

```
typename std::vector<T>::pointer
typename std::vector<T>::const_pointer
```

The actual pointer type used to create the typedef is determined via `std::allocator_traits`

```
typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer pointer;
```

Since each container also has a `value_type` typedef, presumably the purpose of the `pointer` typedef is for some weird situation where the pointer type used is something *other* than `value_type*`.  I've never personally seen a use case for something like that, but I suppose the standards committee wanted to provide the possibility of using custom pointer types with containers.

The problem is that this seems to be inconsistent with the definitions provided for the functions in `std::allocator_traits`.  Specifically, in `std::allocator_traits` we have the `construct` function, which is defined as:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
static void construct(Alloc& a, T* p, Args&&... args);
```

...which just calls `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

But note that this function makes no provisions for a custom pointer type.  The parameter `p` is a plain-old native pointer.

So, why isn't the definition of this function something like:

```
template <class... Args>
static void construct(Alloc& a, typename Alloc::pointer p, Args&&... args);
```

It seems without this, containers which used `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct` would fail if used with an Allocator that defines some custom pointer type.

So, what's going on here?  Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of having `pointer` typedefs in the first place?

Comment: `construct` is/must-be pinned to the element *type*. likewise with `destroy`. `allocate` and `deallocate` are not. Both `allocate` and `deallocate` refer to the `pointer` type you're inspecting. *Neither* of those functions deal with actual object *construction* and *destruction*, and thus have no warrant for pinning to type `T`. Both `construct` and `destroy`, however, *do*.

Comment: @dyp `::std::addressof(*p)`, rather ;)

Comment: The whole idea of `pointer != value_type*` seems to be have been (kind of) introduced in C++11. As far as I understand, in C++03, container implementers could assume `pointer == value_type*`. I'm currently searching the proposals about why it has been changed. It seems to have something to do with the allocator concepts paper (N2654) and potentially the scoped allocator model (N2554).

Comment: After re-reading the papers, it seems that [N2654 - Allocator Concepts (revision 1)](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2654.pdf) removed the restriction that `pointer == value_type*`. This could be related to the use of smart/fancy pointer, e.g. for shared memory allocators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This dichotomy is purposeful, and does not present a problem.  The `construct` member function is typically implemented like this:

```
template <class U, class ...Args>
void
construct(U* p, Args&& ...args)
{
    ::new(static_cast<void*>(p)) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I.e. it forwards to placement `new`, which in turn has this signature:

```
void* operator new  (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
```

So ultimately you need a "real" pointer to call placement new.  And to convey the type of the object that needs to be constructed, it just makes sense to pass that information along in the pointer type (e.g. `U*`).

For symmetry, `destroy` is also formulated in terms of an actual pointer and is typically implemented like so:

```
template <class U>
void
destroy(U* p)
{
    p->~U();
}
```

The main use case for the "fancy pointer" is to place objects into shared memory.  A class called `offset_ptr` is typically used for this purpose, and an allocator can be created to allocate and deallocate memory referred to by `offset_ptr`.  And thus the `allocator_traits` and `allocator` `allocate` and `deallocate` functions traffic in terms of `pointer` instead of `value_type*`.

So the question arises:  If you've got a `pointer`, and need a `T*`, what do you do?

There are two techniques I'm aware of for creating a `T*` from a `pointer p`

`1.`  `std::addressof(*p);`

When you dereference a `pointer p`, it must result in an lvalue according to the standard.  However it would be nice to be able to relax this requirement (e.g. consider a `pointer` returning a proxy reference such as `vector<bool>::reference`). `std::addressof` is specified to to return a `T*` to any lvalue:

```
template <class T> T* addressof(T& r) noexcept;
```

`2.`  `to_raw_pointer(p);  // where:`

```
template <class T>
inline
T*
to_raw_pointer(T* p) noexcept
{
    return p;
}

template <class Pointer>
inline
typename std::pointer_traits<Pointer>::element_type*
to_raw_pointer(Pointer p) noexcept
{
    return ::to_raw_pointer(p.operator->());
}
```

This calls a `pointer`'s `operator->()`, which will either directly return a `T*` or forward to something that will either directly or indirectly return a `T*`.  All `pointer` types *should* support `operator->()`, even if it is referencing a `bool`.  A downside of this technique is that currently `operator->()` is required to not be called unless the `pointer` is dereferenecable.  That restriction should be lifted in the standard.

In C++14 the return type of the second overload (well actually both overloads), can be conveniently replaced with `auto`.

---

If you have a `T*` and wish to construct a `pointer`, you are out of luck.  There is no portable way to convert in this direction.

---

Also note this [tangentially related LWG issue](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1312) about the `vector::data()` member function's return type.  It has bounced between `value_type*`, `pointer` and back, and is currently (and purposefully) `value_type*`.

Comment: What I meant was that this requirement should be relaxed in the standard.  Thanks, I will clarify my careless language.

Comment: *"So ultimately you need a "real" pointer to call placement new."* But surely, the *allocator* should know how to get a `T*` from a `pointer`.. so why isn't it the responsibility of the allocator to do that conversion/extraction?

Comment: That would be an unnecessary addition to the API of the allocator.  Indeed, the C++98/03 allocators actually had such an API in the `address` member function, and that requirement was simply dropped in favor of the more useful standalone utility `std::addressof()`.

Comment: In my comments to the OP, I've speculated about pointer arithmetic. As far as I can see, `pointer` is not required to support pointer arithmetic, so it would be impossible to construct an element at any but the first position of an array - as you say, it's impossible to convert back from `T*` to `pointer`. Could this be another reason?

Comment: @dyp: Nope,  I don't think so.  [allocator.requirements]/p5 says in part: `X::pointer` and `X::const_pointer` shall also satisfy the requirements for a random access iterator (24.2).  And that requires pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Ah thanks! I've missed that last sentence. And it seems libc++ indeed uses `pointer` in many places, such as the `__begin_` and `__end_` members of `vector` and even iterators.