# Correctly allocate memory in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, allocator

I am trying to implement `std::vector` as a programming exercise.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class vector
{
public:
    using size_type = size_t;
    using allocator_type = Allocator;
    ...
private:
    T* m_data;
    allocator_type m_alloc;
    size_type m_capacity;
    ...
};
```

`m_data` has type `T*`. 
I need to allocate memory using `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::allocate(m_alloc, m_capacity)` which returns `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::pointer`.

Can I assume that `pointer` can be implicitly cast to `T*` and assign the value returned from `allocate` to `m_data`?

If not, how to correctly allocate memory in `vector`?

Comment: You could make your own allocator.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28521203/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make your `m_data` member an `Allocator::pointer`. (You should probably make a local alias of that type in your vector, if you want to follow the standard interface.)

The type is there because some allocators don't deal in raw pointers, like the Boost.Interprocess shared memory allocator, which may use smart pointers depending on configuration.

Comment: If I define `m_data` as `Allocator::pointer`, what should `std::vector::data()` function return? Its return type is `T*`.

Comment: @Hrant You should return `std::addressof(*m_data)`